# Ajax Login Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I need to implement Ajax like behavior for login:

I have this controller:

```
def login
    if request.post?  
      @frontendu = Frontenduser.authenticate(params[:email], params[:login_password], params[:store_id])
      if @frontendu
        session[:frontend_user] = @frontendu.id
        @fuser=Frontenduser.find(session[:frontend_user])
        @fuser.update_attributes(:is_logged =>true)
        @fuser.save
        flash[:message]  = "Login successful."
        redirect_to :back
      else
        redirect_to :back
      end 
  end
  end
```

I have this form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/frontendusers/login" id="signin_form" method="post">
  <div class="field">
    <%= text_field_tag :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= password_field_tag :login_password %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :store_id, store_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="forget uppercalse">
    <a href="#">Forget Username?</a>
  </div>
  <div class="forget uppercalse">
    <a href="#">Forget Password?</a>
  </div>
  <div class="login-button">
    <input type="submit" value="Log In"></input>
  </div>
</form>
```

This works, but I would like to retain the login form and simply show somewhere (I will put appropriate divs) that the login has failed. If it does not fail, then redirect is just fine as it is.

I am beginner in Rails, but I was tasked to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 3 I recommend you to look this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Although this is fairly ugly...

```
def login
  if request.post?  
    @frontendu = Frontenduser.authenticate(params[:email], params[:login_password], params[:store_id])
    if @frontendu
      session[:frontend_user] = @frontendu.id
      @fuser=Frontenduser.find(session[:frontend_user])
      @fuser.update_attributes(:is_logged =>true)

      # change this part
      if @fuser.save
        flash[:message]  = "Login successful."
        redirect_to :back
      else 
        # do something here
      end

      # original function
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end 
  end
end
```

I would suggest you scaffold an example controller and use it as an example.

```
rails g controller TestyMcTest
```

You also should take advantage of the context the request is occurring is. This will be the format portion of the scaffold-ed controller. You can do different things based upon the type of request.